# Windows Service Communicate with another Windows Service, Locally

Tags: c#, service

**.NET 3.5 SP1 Only**

I have a service (Service1) that speaks to a remote host, My plan is to include a seperate windows service (service2) that will receive data forwarded to me from Service1. I then process that data and send it back to Service1.

***For example:***

```
Server --> Data --> Service1 --> SpecificData --> Service2
   *Service2 Processes everything, even if Service1 is not running.
   *Service1 is Running again...
Service2 --> SpecificData ---> Service1 --> Data --> Server
```

***I found information on:***

```
IPC, Shared Memory, and Sockets.
```

Sockets seem like the simplest way to go about this, but is it safest way? What I mean by safest; stable way of communication between two local services.

I came across this answer which is what i'm leaning towards at the moment.
[Communication between different C# based services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486917/communication-between-different-c-sharp-based-services)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET framework has some higher level abstractions that might be easier to use and already include some security mechanisms.  Maybe check out:

NetPeerTcpBinding:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netpeertcpbinding(v=vs.90).aspx